# vs code: zoom code tab only

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm an Atom user and just installed VS Code today as a recommendation from a friend. I have to say I'm pretty impressed so far :)

I frequently use the `cmd +` in Atom and I really like the fact that they increase only the code font size. In VS Code `cmd +` by default increases the size of the entire window, which seems that is better for accessibility reasons.

Is there another command/plugin that I can use that can easily change the font size of my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/peterjuras/vsc-fontsize-shortcuts

Font size shortcuts did the trick for me

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

As of [version 1.24](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_24#_font-zoom-commands), VS Code natively supports modifying the font size through commands that can be bound to keys in your keybindings.json file.

For reference, the VS Code team provided example keybindings to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> to increase the font size on Windows. The example keybindings for Windows are reprinted in full below.

```
{ "key": "ctrl+numpad_add",      "command": "editor.action.fontZoomIn" },
{ "key": "shift+ctrl+=",         "command": "editor.action.fontZoomIn" },
{ "key": "ctrl+=",               "command": "editor.action.fontZoomIn" },
{ "key": "ctrl+numpad_subtract", "command": "editor.action.fontZoomOut" },
{ "key": "shift+ctrl+-",         "command": "editor.action.fontZoomOut" },
{ "key": "ctrl+-",               "command": "editor.action.fontZoomOut" },
{ "key": "ctrl+numpad0",         "command": "editor.action.fontZoomReset" },
{ "key": "ctrl+0",               "command": "editor.action.fontZoomReset" },
```

Comment: this will act not on ONE tab, but on ALL tabs/editor